# making a dropdown selector date for airbnb SingleDatePicker

Tags: datepicker, react-dates

I've got my setup like this, I'm absolutely squeezing the limits of what is possible from outside a library:

```
const [customDate, setCustomDate] = useState(moment());
const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);)
const onDropDownChangeMonth = ()=>{
    setCustomDate(moment('07-12-2020', dateFormat.MM_DD_YYYY));
    setFocused(true);
}

    <SingleDatePicker
              date={customDate}
              onDateChange={onDateChange}
              focused={focused}
              placeholder={props.placeholder}
              onFocusChange={(e) => {
                setFocused(e.focused); 
              }}
              navPrev={<div></div>}
              navNext={<div></div>}
              keepFocusOnInput={true}
              renderMonthText={() => (
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                  <select style={{ border: 'none', background: '#ffffff' }} onChange={onDropDownChangeMonth}>
                    <option>January</option>
                    <option>February</option>
                    <option>March</option>
                    <option>April</option>
                    <option>May</option>
                    <option>June</option>
                    <option>July</option>
                    <option>August</option>
                    <option>September</option>
                    <option>October</option>
                    <option>November</option>
                    <option>December</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              )}
            />
```

so, my current implementation gives me correct result like this:

[image]

Since, this would re-render, I wanted to keep it open(I can bear the flicker), the date changes, the calendar changes,the calendar stays open, but, the children they render blank:
[image]

Only when I manually defocus, and reopen then the calendar gets rendered, and I see the changes reflected. How do I get the calendar rendered? How to make it so that I don't have to manually defocus it, I don't mind the flicker.

BTW: I'm using the [`SingleDatePicker` by airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a possible solution for anyone who doesn't mind a *blink* instead of a *flicker*(please read the question above). It's a hacky solution, and it doesn't do much good in my case, just noting here for someone who might be okay with this, **or someone who knows how to reduce this blink to a flicker or nothing**:

```
put this in the `onDropDownChangeMonth`:   
  
const onDropDownChangeMonth = ()=>{
    setCustomDate(moment('07-12-2020', dateFormat.MM_DD_YYYY));
    setFocused(false);
    setTimeout(()=>setFocused(true), 1);
}
```

Even though I put a 1ms timeout, the delay for the re-render is about 1 second, and *this is not good in my case.*. Please mention anything to reduce or get rid of that *delay-for-re-render*.